# What happens if I use close() on a char array?

Tags: c++

I had an interesting question. I have:
`char buf[100]`
And I decided to try using `close(buf)`
Code compiled, the program works. But is there any point in using close() like this?
Thank you.

Comment: I doubt it, but to explain what is actually happening with your code we would need to **see** the code. The context matters, for instance what header files did you include, what compiler did you use, what declarations were in place at the point where you called `close`, etc, etc.

Comment: Totally depends on what `close` does. No clue what it does, so I can't answer.

Comment: I don't think that code should have compiled.  When I try it (using Xcode on a Mac) I get this error:  `temp.cpp:8:8: error: no matching function for call to 'close'
       close(buf);
       ^~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/unistd.h:437:6: note: 
      candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'char [100]' to
      'int' for 1st argument
int      close(int) __DARWIN_ALIAS_C(close);`

Comment: I only have a warning, but yes, something is wrong

Comment: If you have a warning, then it is C and you used the improper tag C++.

Comment: It will return -1 with `errno` set to `EBADF`, because the address of a `char` array is vanishingly unlikely to be a valid file descriptor; assuming it even compiles. Don't do this. And don't waste your time and ours thinking of other meaningless operations and asking what will happen if you do them.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "close" is the function from posix, most likely nothing will happen but it's also possible stuff could break badly.

Arrays in c and c++ decay to pointers, close takes an int. Implicitly converting a pointer to an int is not allowed by the c++ spec but some compilers allow it anyway (doing some testing it looks like modern g++ only allows it if -fpermissive is specified).

Most likely the integer that results from said conversion will be large, file descripters are usually small, so most likely close will just return a bad file descriptor error and do nothing but if it does happen to match a file descriptor then things could get interesing.....

Answer (score 0):

- It should not compile. The compiler should emit warnings.
- The behaviour is undefined
- No, there is no point in using close on a char array

There is also no meaning in doing that. What would you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes, I get a warning when compiling. I randomly mixed up the variables. I originally wanted to use it with a file descriptor and then just got an interest in what's going on.

Comment: If it doesn't compile the compiler will emit *errors.*

Comment: The point is that you said 'the compiler should emit warnings' when you should have said 'should emit errors'. This should not need any explaining.

Comment: @ArminMontigny -- "it should not compile, it should emit warnings" -- that's not accurate. If code is ill-formed, the language definition requires the compiler to "issue a diagnostic". Having done that, the compiler is free to continue to compile the code, with a meaning that depends on the compiler. The language definition does not distinguish "errors" from "warnings". Either one would be "a diagnostic".